# x64 Windows: Why is ExAllocatePool stepping on the caller's stack?

Tags: windows, x86-64

I am playing around with windbg on a 64-bit machine and noticed something interesting:

```
nt!ExAllocatePool:
    ...
    sub rsp, 0xd0
    ...
    mov qword ptr [rsp+0xf8], rbx
```

Windows only allocated 0xd0 bytes for locals but then it decides to step on the callers stack since 0xf8 is > 0xd0! What am I missing here? **This HAS to be a bug in Windows.**

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. This is lacking a little information. So you're saying this was built _with_ frame pointer omission active? What exact build? I'd like to have a look myself.

Comment: This is Windows, I didn't build anything, I just attached a kernel debugger and looked at ntoskrnl

Comment: At what point did I write anything about _you built_ anything? Thing is, you don't provide enough context, so I was asking a very pointed question. And I was also asking about what exact build you are looking at. In my version of `ntoskrnl.exe` `ExAllocatePool()` encompasses **5 instructions** including a `sub rsp, 28h` which clearly doesn't match whatever you have. The `ExAllocatePoolWithTag()` it calls takes merely one more argument, meaning everything fits into registers anyway and stack is used only for locals. But none of what I see matches what you got. So what exact version of ntoskrnl?

Comment: What are the instructions before sub rsp? and does the rsp change afterwards? Please post a longer snippet or tell us where to find this code.